# Prove that an orthonormal sublist and a vector in an inner product space is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $e_1, ... , e_r$ be an orthonormal list. Suppose $v \in V$ such that $\lVert v - e_r \rVert < 1$.

**Prove that $e_1, ... ,e_{r-1}, v$ is linearly independent.**

I was thinking of showing that $v$ and $e_r$ are dependent so $e_1, ..., e_{r-1}, v$ is independent. My attempt uses properties of the norm and inner product, but I am stuck so I think I need to approach this differently. I also think that this might need the usage of the Triangle Inequality Theorem or equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz Theorem. Any help on this would be great!

My attempt:
$$
\lVert v - e_r \rVert < 1 \iff \langle v - e_r, v - e_r \rangle < 1 
\\ \iff \langle v, v - e_r \rangle - \langle e_r, v - e_r \rangle < 1
\\ \iff \overline{\langle v - e_r,v \rangle} - \overline{\langle v - e_r,e_r \rangle} < 1
\\ \iff \overline{\langle v, v \rangle -  \langle e_r, v \rangle} - \overline{\langle v, v \rangle - \langle e_r, e_r \rangle} < 1
\\ \iff \langle v, v \rangle + \langle e_r, v \rangle - \langle v, v \rangle + \langle e_r, e_r \rangle < 1
\\ \iff \langle e_r, v \rangle + 1 < 1
$$

This is where I got stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately this strategy won't work in general, since $\{v,e_r\}$ doesn't have to be linearly dependent. For an example in $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard inner product, take $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ and $v=(0.9,0.1)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for letting me know. How would you recommend I approach this proof?

Comment: Hint: if $\{e_1,\dots,e_{r-1},v\}$ is linearly dependent, show you can write $v=\sum_{j=1}^{r-1} c_je_j$ for some coefficients $c_j$, and then calculate $\|v-e_r\|^2 = \| \sum_{j=1}^{r-1} c_je_j - e_r\|^2$ using the inner product.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you so much! I found the contradiction.